# Can't handle Jasper Validation errors related to jstl

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am creating a javaEE project with jsp and jstl as view module. When i'm trying to bulid it i get different Jasper Validation errors. Using maven and tomcat 9.0.21 as a server, all encodings set to utf-8

I've added jstl-1.2.jar to Project settings -> libraries and to war:exploded -> WEB-INF/lib. I also tried to remove dependencies and set different versions.
If i remove both <%@ taglib %> fmt and c declarations, page is working (at least it doesn't cause server 500 error).

JSP:

```
{<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html lang="${param.lang}">
<fmt:setLocale value="${param.lang}"/>
<fmt:bundle basename="message"/>
<head>
    <title>Book list</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="WEB-INF/css/base.css"/>

</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="row" id="lang">
        <div class="col-2 justify-content-start" id="appName">Library app</div>
        <div class="col-6"></div>
        <div class="col-2 justify-content-end">
            <p id="langLabel">Choose language:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 justify-content-center">
            <a href="?lang=ua"><img src="../WEB-INF/images/uaFlag.jpg" alt="ua"/></a>
            <a href="?lang=en"><img src="../WEB-INF/images/gbFlag.svg" alt="en"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout"  id="logoutForm">
                <button type="submit" id="logoutButton">Logout</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</header>

<div class="row" id="contentDiv">
    <div class="content contentFirstBlock col-7 justify-content-center">
        <div id="addbookFormBlock">
            <form id="addbookForm">
                <fmt:message key="input.addbook.bookName" var="bookName"/>
                <fmt:message key="input.addbook.bookGenre" var="bookGenre"/>
                <fmt:message key="input.addbook.bookIsbn" var="bookIsbn"/>
                <fmt:message key="input.addbook.bookYearPublished" var="bookYearPublished"/>
                <fmt:message key="input.addbook.submitAddBook" var="submitAddBook"/>

                <label for="bookName">${bookName}</label><input type="text" id="bookName" name="bookName" autocomplete="off" required="required"/><br/>
                <label for="bookGenre">${bookGenre}</label><input type="text" id="bookGenre" name="bookGenre" autocomplete="off" required="required"/><br/>
                <label for="bookIsbn">${bookIsbn}</label><input type="text" id="bookIsbn" name="bookIsbn" autocomplete="off" required="required"/><br/>
                <label for="bookYearPublished">${bookYearPublished}</label><input type="text" id="bookYearPublished" name="bookYearPublished" autocomplete="off" required="required"/><br/>
                <input type="submit" id="submitAddButton" name="submitBook" value="${submitAddBook}"/>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content contentSecondBlock col-5">
        <p>Sample</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Select</td>
                <td>Author id</td>
                <td>Author first name</td>
                <td>Author last name</td>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${authors}" var="author">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="aths" value="${author.getAuthorId()}"/></td>
                    <td>${author.getAuthorId()}</td>
                    <td>${author.getAuthorFirstName()}</td>
                    <td>${author.getAuthorLastName()}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>footer</footer>
</body>
</html>}
```

Dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/standard -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/el-api -->

  <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- mySql connector -->

<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

The most recent set of errors:

Error:Jasper Validator: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Error:Jasper Validator: Unable to get JAR resource "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" containing TLD: java.net.MalformedURLException: Path 'http:/java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt' does not start with '/';

Error:Jasper Validator: Unable to find taglib "fmt" for URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt;

Error:Jasper Validator: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException;

Errors i've gotten before:

Error:Jasper Validator: Validation error messages from TagLibraryValidator for c in /admin/addbook.jsp   null: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 784; columnNumber: 8; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the CDATA section. Validation error messages from TagLibraryValidator for fmt in /admin/addbook.jsp null: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 784; columnNumber: 8; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the CDATA section.

Comment: UPDATE: added (to the Project Module Dependencies and WEB-INF/lib) https://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard  Standard Taglib 1.2.3, caused TagLibraryValidator error (the tatter error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i've solved this problem, maybe it will help someone.

Dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.16</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

I just copied code from jsp to another empty jsp file and deleted the first one. After that (and modification of dependencies) validation passes succesfully. Also i removed all jars from WEB-INF/lib and added jstl-1.2.jar to the tomcat/lib folder (i don't know is it needed but if your code is still broken, you can try).